# Write Node app .js configuration during installation process in Inno Setup

Tags: node.js, installation, inno-setup

I found out how to create the wizard pages to collect the information I need. But my app has a `config.js` file, where I need to change some values depending on the user input. What would be the best way to write that file? Write the whole file with `SaveStringToFile` or import the file somehow and replace certain string parts?

This is a snippet from the current config:

```
let cfg = {
  hapi: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    maxUploadBytes: 1000000 * 50 // 50 MB
  },
  jwt: {
    key: 'secretkey',
    algorithm: 'HS256',
    expiresIn: '1h'
  },
  authentication: {
    encryption: {
      saltRounds: 10 // will be used in bcrypt to encrypt passwords
    }
  },
  db_config: {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pw',
    server: 'DESKTOP-IG',
    database: 'TestDB-1'
  },
  scripts: {
    ConnectorInstallPath: "C:\\Program\ Files\\ Connector\\"
  }
}
```

I have to change the values for: `user: 'username'`, `password: 'pw'`, `server: 'DESKTOP-IG'`, `database: 'TestDB-1'`, `port: 3000`, and `ConnectorInstallPath: "C:\\Program\ Files\\ Connector\\"`.

Replacing using a pattern like `server: '*'` would be enough. It doesn't need to be smarter.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function can change a property in your configuration file:

```pascal
function SetConfigProperty(FileName, Name: string; Value: string): Boolean;
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  Count, I, P: Integer;
  HasComma: Boolean;
  Line: string;
  State: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if not LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines) then
  begin
    Log(Format('Error reading %s', [FileName]));
    Result := False;
  end
    else
  begin
    State := 0;

    Count := GetArrayLength(Lines);
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      Line := Lines[I];
      P := Pos(':', Line);
      if (CompareText(Trim(Copy(Line, 1, P - 1)), Name) = 0) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Found property %s at line %d', [Name, (I + 1)]));

        HasComma := (Copy(Trim(Line), Length(Trim(Line)), 1) = ',');

        Line := Copy(Line, 1, P) + ' ' + Value;
        if HasComma then Line := Line + ',';
        Lines[I] := Line;

        Result := SaveStringsToFile(FileName, Lines, False);
        if not Result then
        begin
          Log(Format('Error writing %s', [FileName]));
        end
          else
        begin
          Log(Format('Modifications saved to %s', [FileName]));
        end;

        break;
      end;
      if I = Count - 1 then
      begin
        Log(Format('Property %s not found', [Name]));
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The `Value` must contain complete contents after the colon. With string properties, is has to contain even the quotes. For example:

```pascal
SetConfigProperty(FileName, 'server', '''DESKTOP-IG''');
```

You can use the function for example in the `CurStepChanged` event function in `ssPostInstall` step (when the file is already installed):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FileName: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant('{app}\config.js');
    SetConfigProperty(FileName, 'username', '''' + UsernameEdit.Text + '''');
    SetConfigProperty(FileName, 'Password', '''' + PasswordEdit.Text + '''');
    SetConfigProperty(FileName, 'server', '''' + ServerEdit.Text + '''');
    SetConfigProperty(FileName, 'port', PortEdit.Text);
    { ... }
  end;
end;
```